# Поиск строки, исключая слово через регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет.
Из google doc я получаю огромный html, в котором есть несколько таблиц. В одной из таблиц мне нужно через preg_replace достать фрагмент строки и вставить в другую строку.
Через регулярное выражение пытался искать нужный tr, но в итоге получаю либо все tr из html, либо ничего.
Вот пример моей регулярки:
`'/<tr.*[^(<tr)].+/foreach/.+tr>/g'`
Нужно найти строку, где открывается тег <tr, затем могут идти различные символы, затем обязательно foreach, затем снова какие-то символы, затем закрывающийся /tr>.
При этом внутри не может быть других тегов .

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
^<tr>[^<]+foreach[^<]+<\/tr>$
```

Comment: Внутри тега <tr> могут быть <td>, а в них <span>, <p>...

Comment: Так вроде в вопросе было:  «При этом внутри не может быть других тегов»

Comment: Согласен, моя ошибка в вопросе. Теги внутри могут быть конечно же...

Comment: Ну тогда еще проще: <tr>.+?foreach.+?<\/tr>